# Showing a content block based on an extenal data extension

Tags: ampscript

I'm looking for a string of ampscript to set up my email Header to Show Specific content based on dates in a separate data extension.

My header has 2 different content blocs, and when current date (date of send or even better date of opening) is set as True in this Data extension I'd like to show content A. and when current date is set as False i'd like to show  other content. This is what I have so far.

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @Today, @Circulaire

set @Today = FormatDate(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy") set @rows = LookupRows("Dates-Circulaires","date", @Today) set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @Circulaire = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @Champ
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @Champ = field(@row,"Champ")


  next @Circulaire
 ENDIF ]%%

%%[ if @Champ == 1 then ]%%
 %%[/*TEST - EN - Header Non-Loyauté - avec circulaire*/]%%%%=ContentBlockbyId("2325")=%% 
 %%[ if @Champ == 0 then ]%%
%%[/*TEST - EN Header Non-Loyauté - sans circulaire*/]%% %%=ContentBlockbyId("2326")=%% 
 

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Hi @valérie, do you mind adding some code that you have already attempted to use? From there we can better analyze what you are trying to accomplish and assist. Thanks!

Comment: OK added to the description

Comment: Thanks, I see a few issues here. Why are you through looping the rows? Is the date static in the data extension or is it related to a subscriber? This might be able to be accomplished just using a normal lookup.